# Dynamically Resize one Static Table View Cell's Height in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to do as the title suggests dynamically allocate a certain height dependent on the height of the users device. I have, right now a table view of **8** static cells and in the last one it contains a container view that points to a another table view controller of dynamic cells, Image posted below. Everything was done through to story board so far, however, since there is no way for me to "constrain" a single cell like I can with other elements I was hoping for a solution to my problem here.. Basically in the last cell, the static cell has to dynamically change its height based of the coordinates of "Height of users phone" - "Y coordinate of 7th static cell" is what I would imagine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For what I understand, if all the cells have the same high except the last, what you have to do is implementing the method heightForRowAtIndexPath. For the last cell you make the calculation that you need. I give you an example

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 8 {
        //Returns UITableViewAutomaticDimension or the size you have calculated
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    } else {
        return x.x
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 8 {
        //Returns UITableViewAutomaticDimension or the size you have calculated
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    } else {
        return x.x
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that UITableViewAutomaticDimension is a viable option?